# Merge statement giving error on oracle when trying to merge two tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

i have a student table as :

[image]

I have a `stud_claim` table as is :

[image]

`student_id` is the foreign key of `student` table.

At `stud_claim` table, I have `paid_date` column .paid_date has some data and some row is null.I need to update stu_claim table where paid_date is null and put the value of the service_date in that paid_date,if paid_date is null.To update the paid_date,the another condition for them is to match the `id` of the `student` and `stud_claim` of `stud_claim` table.

I tried using merge statement but its not working:

```
MERGE INTO offc.stud_claim A
USING offc.student B
ON (A.student_id=B.id AND A.PAID_DATE IS NULL)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET A.PAID_DATE=B.SERVICE_DATE
```

Or simply using update statement also ,it is also possible or not?

I got error at:

```
ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "A"."PAID_DATE"
```

I tried from sql also as:

```
update offc.stud_claim a set paid_date=(select id from offc.student b where b.id=a.student_id) where a.paid_id is NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple update statement will be enough for it. There is issue in your update statement.(you are selecting `id` instead of `service_date`)

```
Update offc.stud_claim a 
set paid_date=
(select service_date
   from offc.student b 
  where b.id=a.student_id) 
where a.paid_date is NULL;
```

In `merge` statement, you can not `update` the `column` which are used in `on` clause so you can achieve it using `WHERE` clause as following:

```
MERGE INTO offc.stud_claim A
USING offc.student B
ON (A.student_id=B.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET A.PAID_DATE=B.SERVICE_DATE
WHERE A.PAID_DATE IS NULL;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: ORA-00904: "A"."PAID_ID": invalid identifier

Comment: oh i used paid_id... its paid_ate

Comment: do you think it is possible to do from merge statement? Can i use (A.student_id=B.id AND A.PAID_DATE IS NULL) ?

Comment: You are genius. But sometime it happens when you work on weekends also.

Comment: In merge? Let me give you solution for this type of situation.. but let me clear that the columns used in ON can not be updated but there are other ways. Give me 5 mins

Comment: if u have fb id can u share with me?

Comment: cause u have replied my most of 90% answers

Comment: Haha. Nice to see that you want to be my friend on fb. It's https://www.facebook.com/tejash.hingu

Answer (score 0):

This is how to *update* using simple `UPDATE` of *updatable join view*.

First you join the two tables selecting the column(s) that should be updated and the source column(s) for the update:

```
select a.id, a.service_date, b.paid_date
from student a
join student_claim b
on a.id = b.student_id
where b.paid_date is NULL and
a.service_date is not NULL
```

Note that by execution of this select you may verify, the scoupe if the future `UPDATE`.

I'm e.g. excluding the rows with `service_date is NULL` as you probably would not want to update NULL to NULL (in case that the column is *nullable*)

Than wrap the join query as subquery and perform the `UPDATE` on it.

```
update (
select a.id, a.service_date, b.paid_date
from student a
join student_claim b
on a.id = b.student_id
where b.paid_date is NULL and
a.service_date is not NULL
)
set paid_date = service_date
```

Note that the only precondition to do this is that the table `STUDENT` is *key perserving*. i.e. there is a *unique index* on the joined key (which is most probably the case if `ID` is primary key).

Otherwise you'd get this exception `ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table`.

Contrary to that you may use the `MERGE` statement in case there are more row in STUDENT table with the same `ID`, but the statement will fauil with `ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables`